# Querying Nested Firebase Realtime DB through a specific value

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project with an authentication via Firebase and the Firestore. I get from an external API realtime health data from users, which is then stored in the Realtime DB (which includes an userAccessToken which I know for each user).
The problem now is that I cannot query the users data, as their userAccessToken is deeply nested:

All top nodes from the API:

[image: All top nodes from the API] -

First node and all first children expanded:

[image: First node and all first children expanded]

What possible solutions are there to get the data for that specific user only through the userAccessToken?

I tried, indexing the DB, however this is was not possible because of the nesting and each user having a uniq identifier as first child.
I could retrieve all data from the "ACTIVITY-Activities", and tried to do the filtering client side, this was due to performance not a solution (it did not finish after 30min).

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: There is no way to filter in nested children under `ACTIVITY-Activities` like that in Firebase Realtime Database. The property you order/filter on must be at a fixed path under every direct child nodes, and that's not the case here - as it can be at any index in the `actitivies` array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested, the gist of which is that you'll need to ensure that all the data you want to order/filter on is in a flat list of child nodes.